# Parsing error with mismatched brackets while creating data

Tags: haskell

I have already asked one question about similar theme but now I absolutely do not understand the compile error.

Here is my data structure:

```
data RoseTree = Node Int [RoseTree] deriving Show
```

After that I am trying to create a Tree with different number of Nodes with Leaves,

[image]

```
let rose = Node 1 ([(Node 2 ([])),(Node 3 ([])) ,(Node 4 [])])
let bigrose = Node 1 ([(Node 2 ([(Node 1 ([(Node 2 ([])),(Node 3 ([])) ,(Node 4 [])]))]),(Node 3 ([])) ,(Node 4 [])])
let bigrose1 = Node 1 ([(Node 2 ([(rose)])),(Node 3 ([])) ,(Node 4 [])])
```

But for `bigrose` and `bigrose1` I get such errors as

> ```
> u3.hs:4:1: error:
> parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
>   |
> 4 | let bigrose = Node 1 ([(Node 2 ([(Node 1 ([(Node 2 ([])),(Node 3 ([])) ,(Node 4 [])]))]),(Node 3 ([])) ,(Node 4 [])])
>   |                                                                                                                    ^
> ```

Where have I lost brackets? I have counted all of them but I see that everything is correct...

Comment: Why do you put parenthesis around your lists?

Comment: The `bigrose` is: `bigrose = Node 1 [Node 2 [Node 1 [Node 2 [], Node 3 [], Node 4 []]], Node 3 [], Node 4 []]`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem No) It doesn't work again) The difinition of the type should containt such brackets : "()"

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Simple "rose" works correctly

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I use Lists in order to create a big number of Leaves

Comment: the parentheses are indeed unnecessary, and just make your trees very difficult to read. However, I suspect the parse error is not due to this, but because you are using `let` without `in` - what is your intention here?

Comment: @HerrSgory: no, the parenthesis are not necessary. You can define a rose as `Node 1 []`, and the square brackets of a list act also as "brackets" that thus specify to the parser that this is a subexpression. What if you write the `rose` without parenthesis?

Comment: @RobinZigmond: good point. Unless it is in a `do` block, the `let`s indeed expect an `in`. If the roses are defined at the top level, then one should not use `let`.

Comment: @RobinZigmond
Such thng aso does not work <br>
let bigrose1 = Node 1 ([(Node 2 ([]),(Node 3 ([])) ,(Node 4 [])]) in Node 1 ([(Node 2 ([bigrose1])),(Node 3 ([])) ,(Node 4 [])])

Comment: @HerrSgory: at the top level you do *not* use `let`. One uses `let` to define variables used in an expression, or in a `do` block (without `in`). Just write `rose = ...` (so *without* the `let`).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Actually I have already used 'let' as a variable type && everything was ok. I cannot understand why mine expression is worong in a source file

Comment: @HerrSgory: in `ghci`, you are working in an implicit `do` block.

Comment: `let` before a declaration (with no `in`) works fine in GHCi, but it doesn't in a source file

Comment: `let bigrose1 = Node 1 ([(Node 2 ([]),(Node 3 ([])) ,(Node 4 [])]) in Node 1 ([(Node 2 ([bigrose1])),(Node 3 ([])) ,(Node 4 [])]) ` - this isn't correct, and makes no sense. In this case, as @WillemVanOnsem says, you simply shouldn't use `let` at all. How to actually use `let` is explained [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#let-it-be) (I encourage you to read the first few chapters of this book, if not more, since you appear to be a beginner) - there is no reason to use it in your case.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem
Yes may be I have understood my mistake. I will read more about do block

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help !

Comment: also, if you'd paste the error message properly, you'd see where that `^` points at, like [here](https://repl.it/repls/BoringNewBooleanvalue). (but you're using a different version, apparently)

Answer (score 3):

> Where have I lost brackets? I have counted all of them but I see that everything is correct...

Counting is a task where computers are more reliable than human beings.

Let's use the *ghci* interpreter to tackle the troublesome expression:

```
 λ> 
 λ> data RoseTree  =  Node Int [RoseTree]  deriving  (Eq, Read, Show)
 λ> str0="Node 1 ([(Node 2 ([(Node 1 ([(Node 2 ([])),(Node 3 ([])) ,(Node 4 [])]))]),(Node 3 ([])) ,(Node 4 [])])"
 λ> 
 λ> tree0 = (read str0) :: RoseTree
 λ> tree0
*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
 λ>
```

OK, so *ghci* agrees there is a problem.

Let's use *ghci* to count the parenthesis and square brackets:

```
 λ> 
 λ> length $ filter ( '[' == ) str0
8
 λ> length $ filter ( ']' == ) str0
8
 λ> length $ filter ( '(' == ) str0
13
 λ> length $ filter ( ')' == ) str0
12
 λ>
```

OK, so there is one extra left parenthesis. This is **bad**.

Now that we know what we're looking for, we can indent the faulty expression manually.

```
bigrose0a = Node 1 ([
                       (Node 2 ([
                                    (Node 1 ([
                                                (Node 2 ([])),
                                                (Node 3 ([])),
                                                (Node 4  [])
                                            ])
                                    )
                                ])  -- HERE - FIXED !!!
                       ),
                       (Node 3 ([])),
                       (Node 4 [])
                    ])
```

It turns out that the child list of the first `Node 2` is not properly terminated, just before the last `Node 3`.
We can add the missing right parenthesis, and then re-check things are OK:

```
 λ>
 λ> str1="Node 1 ([(Node 2 ([(Node 1 ([(Node 2 ([])),(Node 3 ([])) ,(Node 4 [])]))])),(Node 3 ([])) ,(Node 4 [])])"
 λ> 
 λ> tree1 = (read str1)  :: RoseTree
 λ> 
 λ> tree1
Node 1 [Node 2 [Node 1 [Node 2 [],Node 3 [],Node 4 []]],Node 3 [],Node 4 []]
 λ>
```

So we are home and dry now. Good.

Note that there is a nice *lazy* alternative. As noted in the comments, given the grammar we have, parenthesis are useless in this context. So let's get rid of them altogether:

```
 λ> 
 λ> str2 = filter  ( \ch -> ch /= '(' && ch /= ')' )  str0
 λ> str2
"Node 1 [Node 2 [Node 1 [Node 2 [],Node 3 [] ,Node 4 []]],Node 3 [] ,Node 4 []]"
 λ> 
 λ> tree2 = (read str2) :: RoseTree
 λ> tree2
Node 1 [Node 2 [Node 1 [Node 2 [],Node 3 [],Node 4 []]],Node 3 [],Node 4 []]
 λ>
```

Now you can just copy/paste the fixed expression from the *ghci* session into your source code; preferably the indented version, I think.

### Side note:

It is difficult to deal with these kind of data structures long term without developing some sort of toolkit. As an example, you can invest the time to write a recursive prettyprinter, and eventually override the regular Show instance for RoseTree and replace it with your own stuff. In that sort of style:

```
import qualified  Data.List  as  L  (intercalate)

data RoseTree  =  Node Int [RoseTree]  deriving  (Eq, Read)

shift :: Int -> String -> String
shift n st = L.intercalate ",\n" $ let  spaces = replicate n ' '
                       in  map (spaces++) (lines st)

roseGenShow :: Int -> Int -> RoseTree -> String
roseGenShow indentStep indentBase (Node v rts) =
    let  ctName = "Node"
         prefix = ctName ++ " " ++ (show v) ++ " ["
    in  if (null rts)
            then  shift indentBase (prefix ++ "]")
            else  let  base    = shift indentBase prefix
                       indent1 = indentBase + indentStep
                       rtss    = L.intercalate ",\n" $
                                 map  (roseGenShow indentStep indent1)  rts
                  in  base ++ "\n" ++ rtss ++ "\n" ++ (shift indentBase "]")

roseShow :: RoseTree -> String
roseShow rt = roseGenShow 4 0 rt

instance Show  RoseTree  where  show = roseShow


rose     = Node 1 ([(Node 2 ([])),(Node 3 ([])) ,(Node 4 [])])
bigrose  = Node 1 ([(Node 2 ([(Node 1 ([(Node 2 ([])),(Node 3 ([])) ,(Node 4 [])]))])),(Node 3 ([])) ,(Node 4 [])])
bigrose1 = Node 1 ([(Node 2 ([(rose)])),(Node 3 ([])) ,(Node 4 [])])


main = do
    putStrLn $ "bigrose = "
    putStrLn $ roseShow bigrose
    putStrLn $ ""
    putStrLn $ "bigrose1 = "
    putStrLn $ (show bigrose1)
```

### Program output:

```
bigrose = 
Node 1 [
    Node 2 [
        Node 1 [
            Node 2 [],
            Node 3 [],
            Node 4 []
        ]
    ],
    Node 3 [],
    Node 4 []
]

bigrose1 = 
Node 1 [
    Node 2 [
        Node 1 [
            Node 2 [],
            Node 3 [],
            Node 4 []
        ]
    ],
    Node 3 [],
    Node 4 []
]
```

Also, you could write a specialized parser for RoseTree expressions, which could give you better error messages than the GHC compiler or *ghci*.

Comment: in `"(Node 2 ([ ... ]) ,"` the list's parens are perfectly well balanced. it's the superfluous parens around the `Node 2 _` that are not closed. `"(Node 2 ([ ... ]) ,"` could conceivably be a start of a well-formed expression too, of some *tuple* type, so removing the `'('` in the matching `"(Node 4 [])" would make it parse too -- and then fail due to a type mismatch.

Comment: also, your `bigrose0a` has balanced parens, you've already added a paren there, but it's not clear in the wording that you did.

Comment: @Will Ness - yes, you're right, it's already fixed there. I have added a suitable comment in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any parens-matching capable editor, like e.g. the one at https://ideone.com/,  to carefully align the stuff vertically with indentation so that the structure is easily and clearly seen,

[image]

and discover the missing parenthesis that way.

There really is one that's missing, as the error message indeed tells us.

Update: even better, use DrRacket's editor:

[image]

It even correctly identifies the superfluous parens around the `Node 2 _` that aren't closed. `( Node 2 ([ ... ]) ,` could conceivably be a start of a well-formed expression too, of some *tuple* type, so removing the `(` in the matching `( Node 4 [] )` would make it parse too (and then fail due to a type mismatch).